# Using custom structure in opencl

Tags: data-structures, opencl

I'm trying to use custom data structure with OpenCL kernel. I defined in my host program a simple structure like :

```
struct myStruct{
   cl_ulong n_occ;
   cl_ulong start_time;
   cl_ulong end_time;
   cl_ulong exec_time;
   cl_ulong total_time;
   cl_float avg_time;
} myStruct_t;
```

The equivalent custom data structure definition is also done in my OpenCL kernel.

```
struct myStruct{
   unsigned long n_occ;
   unsigned long start_time;
   unsigned long end_time;
   unsigned long exec_time;
   unsigned long total_time;
   float avg_time;
} myStruct_t;
```

The kernel function is the following :

```
__kernel void process_data( __global myStruct_t* input, __global myStruct_t* output){
    output->start_time = input->start_time;
    output->end_time = input->end_time;
    output->exec_time = input->end_time - input->start_time;
    output->total_time = input->total_time + output->exec_time;
    output->n_occ = input->n_occ + 1;
    output->avg_time = output->total_time / output->n_occ;
}
```

I use an Nvidia card as GPU device. After the execution of the kernel code, I obtained incorrect results. I don't understand the reason. is there something missing ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect results"? What was the input, what is the output?

Comment: Are you working only on one input and one output ? If so, what is the reason to run this on a kernel ? If you do it on multiple input/output, shouldn't your code be like `output[id].start_time = input[id].start_time;` in your kernel ?

Comment: It was just a simple initiation on using custom structure in OpenCL. The next step will consist to give a large vector of custom structure to an OpenCL kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked to see if your host struct (C) is [packed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Default_packing_and_.23pragma_pack) correctly (also ensure that the OpenCL side is [packed correctly](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/attributes-types.html) and that both report the same size)? It is also probably a good idea to use the same cl_* types in both structs.

Comment: How to know if the host struct and the OpenCL side struct is correctly packed and report both of them the same size ?   Do you think I'm not using the same cl_* types in both structs? I think i use the same types.

Comment: I meant - use the actual types because its a better practice. However that doesn't seem to be your problem - you're definitely the victim of some padding/packing artifact. Try the #pragma and the OpenCL "__attribute__ ((packed))" first.

Comment: A simple way to ensure the sizes are correct is to declare a field called size as the very first field and fill the value on the CL device. Then check the returned value in the buffer struct with one returned by "sizeof" on the host.